# Reading PDF through FPGA

Tags: fpga

I am a newbie in FPGA world, working out on Verilog these days. I have thought of a couple of Projects for my FinalYearProject at my college. One of them is Handheld Ebook Reader. Well, I will workout the other things required, what i am most concerned about is, How am i going to read a pdf file through FPGA.

Well, in the project, i will be interfacing a MicroSD card module with FPGA, the FPGA would read the file from pdf and would display it on LCD, interfacing with LCD wouldnt be a big problem as i have got a couple of good resources for that, interfacing the memory card module too. But the thought that has been troubling me in choosing this project is, how am I going to read PDF. I may work on the pdf which has texts only, i wont work on images, on the other hand if i plan to work on images as well, i will have to do a lot of work for several tasks, say for zooming in and others. 
  Kindly help me on this.
  Plus, i am pretty keen about this task. Kindly tell me if this can be done more easily with microcontroller. I have a little bit of experience working with them.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First of all you need to determine what you're going to do with the PDF. If you're displaying it, you'll need some memory for the frame buffer, and a way to interface with the display. That should be your primary concern. Then, start thinking about rendering the PDF itself. As PDFs are essentially compressed PostScript of one form or another with embedded fonts, you can divide your tasks into some major elements:

- part of the FPGA to load data from SD card or other media including file system access
- part of the FPGA to decompress chunks of data, or to accelerate this process
- part of the FPGA to decompress image data (JPEG, PNG, etc.) and copy to memory
- part of the FPGA to decode/execute PostScript
- part of the FPGA to figure out what needs to be displayed (such as the current page); this could be simple bounding logic or complex scaling logic handling a variety of different display modes
- a floating point unit for the floating point coordinates in PostScript
- an integer ALU
- several "GPU" engines which render primitives from the PostScript engine (ideally, in parallel) e.g. draw line, draw polygon, ...
- a font engine or two to render fonts (this will likely be very complex as you will need to support complex features like hinting and antialiasing.)
- a display interface and memory interface
- a UI controller of some kind, perhaps implementing copy/paste, selections, menus, etc.

Ideally the engines 1-5 would be pipelined to get maximum throughput. You'll be looking at a big FPGA to do all of this.

You could probably do this on a CPU, but if you realllly want to do it on an FPGA, this is probably the route to take.

Comment: I would start of by using the FPGA as a CPU....

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure if images will make things harder; zooming in on text is hard enough as it is. If you want to do things by FPGA you definitely want a soft processor, i.e. a microcontroller on a part of your FPGA. Decoding PDFs is not something you want to do parallel like an FPGA works. FPGA suppliers like Xilinx and Altera offer IP for controllers, but the problem may be that a PDF library may not be available for them. In this you'll have better chances with an external controller, which uses the FPGA as a display driver.

Comment: What if I work with .txt files, just extracting the text and displaying it. How would I extract the text even from a .txt file.

Comment: That's much easier - you have a font bitmap and a RAM display buffer, both using the FPGA internal block RAM. Youadisplay the bitmap of each each  character on the appropriate part of the screen according to the content of the display buffer. A seperate section copies the text into the display buffer and formats.  You can initialise the RAM at compile time with known text while developing the display part.  This could readily be done without a CPU, especially if you avoid/simplify the FAT stiff to read the SD card. This is an entirely viable starter FPGA project. Way more so than PDF.

Comment: Going to a character display buffer instead of a graphics bitmap brings the memory requirement down to what is available on-chip in a cheap FPGA

Answer (score 4):

Put a CPU (some kind of micro-controller core) into your FPGA, and then program a PDF reader for that CPU. Going this route, you might want to consider NOT doing PDF, but doing HTML instead, as that format is a bit more amenable to the sort of wrapping and re-sizing that you'll want to do on a reader. There are any number of HTML rendering libraries out there that you could re-purpose to whatever CPU you embed.

Comment: More like the start should be from displaying raw images on LCD and later all that fancy stuff...

Answer (score 2):

As others have said, you probably want to do the PDF decoding as software on a soft-core processor.

One of the major requirements this will impose is that you are likely to need a number of megabytes of external ram, for both the program code and the data.

Theoretically, with enough memory, any processor could be made to decode a PDF... it just may be slow in operation and painful to develop if you have to write it from scratch.

Also you will likely need more RAM than is available on chip in an affordable FPGA in order to form the video frame buffer for an LCD of a size worth displaying a PDF on (though a monochrome smartphone-size display probably would fit).  You'll either need to have dual port video memory or craft an arbiter to allow the processor logic to write to it interleaved with the display logic clocking bits out.

Frankly speaking, an e-reader is not a good FPGA appliction, it's a system-on-chip one, architecturally very similar to a smartphone.  One might add a cheap fpga as a pin-remapper to make the same PCB usable with a variety of commodity LCD glass modules, but the logic belongs in a nice modern ARM core or similar.

Answer (score 2):

An FPGA is really not the right device to do this sort of task. There are CPUs with all the required peripherals to do the job (e.g.LPC2478) which will be cheaper and draw a ton less power.
If you want to do it with an FPGA as a learning excercise, I'd suggest you break the task down and start off By making your life easier by preprocessing the book content on a PC into a file format that is easier to display than PDF, e.g. uncompressed bitmap or run length coded bitmaps. And start off using a simple block-oriented filesystem, as doing FAT stuff on an FPGA will be quite complicated.
That way you should be able to get something working reasonably quickly, then look at doing more complex stuff like other file format etc. later. If you start off trying to do it all, there is a high chance you will spend a ton of time and have nothing working to show for it when you get bored or run out of time.
At some point you definitely will need to using be using a CPU, either external or on the FPGA.